# JavaScript / jQuery parse xml

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanted to get like count numbers from this link

```
http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=links.getStats&urls=http://www.apple.com

var xml = "http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=links.getStats&urls=http://www.apple.com;"
var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml),
$xml = $(xmlDoc),
$title = $xml.find( "like_count" );
$('.countnumber').text($title.text());
```

however, I got this error

> Uncaught Error: Invalid XML:
>   http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=links.getStats&urls=http://www.apple.com;

Is there a way to parse it by javascript?

Thanks

Comment: What does `xml` contain?

Comment: You have to get your xml first, you're only giving jquery a link to an xml document

Comment: because the contents of `xml` is not a xml value.. it is a url... you need to read the contents of the url first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case `xml` contains a resource url, not a xml string that is the cause of the error. You need to read the contents of the url first then parse it.

You need to read the contents of the URL

```
var xml = "http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=links.getStats&urls=http://www.apple.com;"
$.get(xml).done(function(xml){
    var $xml = $(xml),
        $title = $xml.find( "like_count" );
    console.log($title.text())
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/XLaha/)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments retrieve your xml first.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=links.getStats&urls=http://www.apple.com;",
    dataType: "xml"
}).done(function(data) {
    var $xml = $(data),
        $title = $xml.find("like_count");
    $('.countnumber').text($title.text());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a string representing your xml, not the URI to the resource.  Also, `parseXML` isn't even neccessary.

You need to use AJAX to get the XML:

```
    var xml = "http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?       method=links.getStats&urls=http://www.apple.com;";

    $.get(xml, function(data){
      var xmlDoc = $(data);
      .. your code here
    });
```